# Firebase firestore - Data must be an object, but it was: a custom Object object

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using Firestore in conjunction with realtime database in order to provide a user presence system for my application.

**Update: article I followed**

https://blog.campvanilla.com/firebase-firestore-guide-how-to-user-presence-online-offline-basics-66dc27f67802

In one of the methods I use this code here:

```
const usersRef = this.$fireStore.collection('users').doc(uid)
const whoIsOnlineRef = this.$fireDb.ref('.info/connected')

whoIsOnlineRef.on('value', (snapshot) => {
    this.$fireDb.ref(`/status/${uid}`)
        .onDisconnect()
        .set('offline')
        .then(() => {
          usersRef.set({ online: true }, { merge: true })

          this.$fireDb.ref(`/status/${uid}`).set('online')
        })
})
```

The .set method, however, is giving me the error mentioned in the title and I can't quite understand why. I'm simply passing a javascript object to .set method and this should technically work.

Can you spot what is wrong with the code?

Comment: I'm gonna guess that you can't make changes to Firestore in your onDisconnect handler.  That handler will effectively queue up some changes *in RTDB* when the connection is dropped.  RTDB doesn't know anything about Firestore.

Comment: You might want to read this guide: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/presence

Comment: Let me give you some more context otherwise it may be confusing

Comment: I did read that and then ended up also on this one: https://blog.campvanilla.com/firebase-firestore-guide-how-to-user-presence-online-offline-basics-66dc27f67802

It should work, as far as I can tell. I don't see reasons why it wouldn't

Comment: You're not using Cloud Functions to proxy the change from RTDB to Firestore.  You're trying to do this only on the client, which will not work.

Comment: The cloud function that you can see in the article is up and running already. As you can see in the blog post the function is triggered by the change on the /status field of the real time database and that works well.

Comment: In the frontend I'm simply setting the status to 'online' when the user logs in. The rest is then handled in the cloud function (which does work alright). The only thing that is giving me troubles is the .set() method on the firestore instance

Comment: Neither the blog nor the documentation suggests that you can make changes to Firestore in your onDisconnect handler.  You are supposed to make changes to Firestore in the Cloud Function as a result to the change to RTDB that you make in your onDisconnect handler.

Comment: The code I used is literally the same as in the blog. Again, that is the **then** statement, not the onDisconnect handler. In fact, if I remove everything in that code snippet and I simply leave the firestore update I keep getting the same error.

As mentioned, the error seems to be with the set() method (and update as a matter of fact) and not with the rest.

Comment: Are you using angular or some wrapper around the core javascript APIs?  Angular doesn't often closely match core JS in terms of exact usage.

Comment: That is implemented in a Vuex store action (using Vue)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the reason why this wasn't working is that the code was running on the server in an SSR application.

I moved that very same logic to the browser and it started working nicely. I still don't see why this wouldn't work in the server as, at the end of the day I was still passing a simple js object to the .set() method.

Either way, there you have it