# "Function DocumentReference.set() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: a custom object" Error on adding data to doc?

Tags: angular, firebase

I am using angular with firebase and was trying to add data to my firestore collection using the below code: But i keep getting the error:

```
ERROR FirebaseError: Function DocumentReference.set() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: a custom object (found in document web_record_tab_test/Z7zP7Tze1OwZfPkFKJph
```

I have tried the different answers given on another stackoverflow question but could not fina a solution to this. Here is my code:

```
let dataArray=dataAppFormat.map((obj)=> {return Object.assign({}, obj)});
let data={
  data: dataArray,//.map((obj)=> {return Object.assign({}, obj)}),
  load: "updated",
  type:"RichTextBlock"
};
let ref=this.firestore.collection('web_record_tab_test');
ref.doc().set(data).then(function() {
  console.log("Document successfully written!");
```

Here dataAppFormat is an array which i have created into an array of JS objects and made a Js object and tried to add it into the document. Any suggestions on where i may be going wrong?

Comment: I had a similar problem, but with Nuxt SSR. I had to switch my app to an SPA (client rendering only) per this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57473203/705296